# broadcaster permission for android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-broadcastreceiver

I recently did a code scan on my Android source code using HPFortify service. They reported security vulnerability regarding one of the broadcast receivers. They suggested to use the broadcaster permission to reduce the attack vector. This way you are restricting broadcaster, otherwise any malicious application can send the intent and broadcast receiver will process it.

Here is a my actual code:

```
String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
IntentFilter smsFilter = new IntentFilter(SMSReceiver.ACTION);
                    smsFilter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    smsReceiver = createSMSReceiver(ctx, l);
                    ctx.registerReceiver(smsReceiver, smsFilter);
```

I am using the following permission to listen to the permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Ideally the last line of the code should be like:

```
 ctx.registerReceiver(smsReceiver, smsFilter, "XXX.boradcaster.permission.XXX", null);
```

I am not able to figure out the broadcast receiver permission. Can anyone suggest how to figure out this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission you're looking for is `"android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"`, or you can use the `android.Manifest.permission.BROADCAST_SMS` constant.

Comment: How did you figure out this permission? Can you give me more information?

Comment: Just by searching. I don't recall exactly where I found that one way back when, but when the SMS API went public, [the blog page](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1) with the details included it in the example code. If something like that isn't readily available in the docs or developer pages, the surefire way to find it is to search the source code. In this case, you'd search for the package broadcasting that action, then check its manifest for the relevant permissions.

Comment: If the broadcast isn't sent by the system, but, e.g., by a third-party app, then the permission should be stated in their docs. If not, you can use `PackageManager` to inspect an app's manifest, or decompile the APK. And, of course, if it's your own app broadcasting it, you already know the permission. Failing all of that, you can ask a question on Stack Overflow. :-)